# Как правильно отправить JSON с помощью cURL?

Tags: php, json, post, curl, парсер

Добрый день,уважаемое сообщество.
Недавно пришлось столкнуться с cURL`ом,понравилось...пытаюсь разобраться лучше.
В связи с этим появилась мысль написать скрипт который бы использовал возможности этой библиотеки.
**Идея:**
У нас есть сайт,где постят пароли к ближайшим фрироллам во всех популярных покер-румах.
Есть возможность через форму выбрать определенный тип игры и определенный рум.
Я в скрипте заранее посылаю необходимые параметры и заголовки в обрабатываю уже конечную страницу,только с интересующей информацией.

**Что не получилось:**
С помощью FireBugа  было установлено,что данные которые необходимо послать - JSON.
**Вопрос1:** Правильно ли я делаю,что посылаю данные на http://www.pokerist.by/json/freerolls/filter/',а в заголовках указываю [http://www.pokerist.by/freerolls/raspisanie-frirollov/,как](http://www.pokerist.by/freerolls/raspisanie-frirollov/,%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA) реферера?? 
Или необходимо посылать данные на http://www.pokerist.by/freerolls/raspisanie-frirollov и поставить переход по ридеректам в опциях?
**Вопрос2:** почему,после отработки скрипта в результате я получаю NULL.Где ошибка??Получается,что данные не были отправлены??
**Вопрос3:** почему запуска скрипта, в FireBug`е,я вижу только (см.скрин3),и не вижу заголовков которые послал курлом?

**Скрипт,скрины FireBug`а**

```html
<?php
$data = array( "rooms"=>[4],"games"=>["HOLDEM_NOLIMIT"],"daysToDisplay"=>3,
               "payOutTypes"=>[0,1,2],"maxPayout"=>"100000","minPayout"=>"0","isDeposited"=>false,
               "isPassworded"=>true,"isByinned"=>false,"isTicketed"=>false,"isOtherConditioned"=>false,
               "isNoRestriction"=>false,"isPrivate"=>false
);
$json_data = json_encode($data);

$curl_desc = curl_init('http://www.pokerist.by/json/freerolls/filter/');
curl_setopt($curl_desc, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl_desc, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl_desc, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl_desc, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl_desc, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
curl_setopt($curl_desc, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_desc, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_data),
            'Referer: http://www.pokerist.by/freerolls/raspisanie-frirollov/',
            'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
            'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01')
);
$result = curl_exec($curl_desc);
var_dump(json_decode($result));
```

Что,я вижу на оригинальном сайте
Заголовки:
[image: Что вижу на оригинальном сайте:]

POST-данные
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я вижу в FireBug`e после работы моего скрипта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это не парсер и не граббер контента,я уважаю труд разработчиков и авторские права.
Никаких целей,кроме "разобраться как работает и что я делаю не так",я не преследую.
Благодарю за уделенное время,и Ваш опыт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сервер возвращает HTML код, а не JSON. Поэтому json_decode возвращает NULL.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы можете узнать, был отправлен запрос или нет, включив лог:

```
$curl_log = fopen("curl_log.txt", 'w+');
curl_setopt($curl_desc, CURLOPT_STDERR, $curl_log);
curl_setopt($curl_desc, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
```

Comment: Благодарю,Вас.
Действительно,убрав json_decode(),я получил необходимые данные.
За лог - отдельное спасибо.