# Как правильно передать заголовки в json

Tags: php, json, curl

Помогите.

В неком API, нужно получить ответ в формате json

> может принимать как post параметры(по умолчанию) так и json, при
>   передачи json необходимо обязательно передать http заголовок
>   content-type: application/json.

В запросе нужно передать еще и заголовки

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://site.com/status');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$headers = [
    'api_sign: '.$sha256,
    'public_key: '.$pub_key
];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Что бы правильно отослать и получить в json формате, надо все данные json_encode
Если я делаю

```
$headers =json_encode($headers);
$post=json_encode($post);
```

то сервер отдает "неправильная аутентификация".
Как заголовки передать правильно?

Comment: "Неправильная аутенфикация" - означает, что Вам нужно авторизоваться, и сохранить сессию, прежде чем тыкать курлом в сервер.

Comment: нет. если я делаю это пост запросом аутентификация проходит
она и есть в $headers  
это API.
вот что тут аунтефикация:
    $sha256 = hash('sha256', $post.$priv_key);

Если я не кодирую в json - все работает, но тогда сервер не отдает json

Comment: заголовки то вы на кой кодируете?

Comment: @DeLEsprit а ничего, что Вы два раза CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER устанавливаете?

Comment: Возможный дубль https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445084/Как-правильно-отправить-json-с-помощью-curl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Михаил Алексеевич спасибо, действительно - дважды отсылаю CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER